# Difference between fuzzy vault and fuzzy commitment?

Tags: encryption, cryptocurrency, two-factor-authentication

https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2905055.2905118

Quoting the above paper's abstract, "Biometric cryptosystem can apply fuzzy vault, fuzzy commitment, helper data and secure sketch, whereas, cancelable biometrics uses distorting transforms, Bio-Hashing, and Bio-Encoding techniques."

It differentiates between a fuzzy vault and a fuzzy commitment scheme. How are the two different? Where does fuzzy extractor lie in this context?